# drupal to create website

Tags: drupal

I want to create website.I have installed drupal in my system.I have downloaded some themes.created menus and contents also.How can i connect content pages to menus. 
All default drupal menus will remain same?how can i display only newly created menus.
Is it possible to alter images??

Please let me know the answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Here's your menu answer: http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/menu

Comment: user393043, the question you're asking is very simple. I would suggest you pick up a good book on Drupal and read it. Posting very simple questions like this on Stackoverflow is probably not the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can seach what you want in [Drupal Modules](http://drupal.org/project/Modules), or search in some modules configuration, or code it.

Answer (score 0):

There are menu settings on each node where you can add them to any menu, you like. You can move any menuitem everywhere on admin/build/menu. For Image-Support I recomment you play a bit with the CCK module and it's possibilities. There is an ImageField module to extend CCK.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has very nice handbook and reading it will solve most of your problems.